# Can I use setOnClickListener in MVVM pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

Can I use setOnClickListener in MVVM pattern? Or is it better to just use xml's onClick?

Comment: It's the same thing, the XML way is just a different (and more limited) way to declare it. The results are basically the same, your `View` gets wired up to a function it calls when there's a click. And click listeners are a UI (*View* in MVVM) thing anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setOnClickListener function can be used anywhere in kotlin class like activity, fragment, or adapter regardless of the design pattern. And it's the better approach than using onClick on your XML files

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can user setOnClickListener, personally I don't like to use xml onClick